# php mysqli select unique rows from duplicate and partially duplicate rows

Tags: mysql, group-by, unique

I have a dataset like

```
lvl0        lvl1            lvl2         lvl3
jfierf4jfi  personifi6916   dentari54    knead314                                               
jfierf4jfi  personifi6916   dentari54    traf8                                              
jfierf4jfi  personifi6916   herculeses4                                                 
jfierf4jfi  personifi6916   dentari54                                                   
jfierf4jfi  personifi6916
```

Where `lvl0` to `lvl3` are columns. There are 14 columns like this, where non-populated column values are `NULL`. I want to select only longest unique rows, eliminating all partially duplicate rows.

As from given data I want to extract this

```
lvl0        lvl1            lvl2         lvl3
jfierf4jfi  personifi6916   dentari54    knead314                                               
jfierf4jfi  personifi6916   dentari54    traf8                                              
jfierf4jfi  personifi6916   herculeses4
```

The rows with Partially duplicate values are eliminated.

I have tried with `DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` but they are resulting in all the rows without eliminating the partially duplicate ones.

I have tried these

```
SELECT DISTINCT lvl3,lvl2,lvl1,lvl0 FROM table; 
and 
SELECT * FROM table GROUP BY lvl3,lvl2,lvl1,lvl0;
```

Comment: This is next to impossible to answer. Please edit your question to contain the code that you tried and also post the db schema.

Comment: `DISTINCT` will only remove rows where _all_ the columns you're selecting are identical. So if you have 100 rows with 10 identical columns and one unique, it will still return all rows.

Comment: Is there no solution to this?

Comment: You say you used both; but not together right? Try them "together" and not as 2 separate ways. That most likely will solve this.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner please give me an example. thanks

Comment: `SELECT DISTINCT lvl3,lvl2,lvl1,lvl0 FROM table GROUP BY lvl3,lvl2,lvl1,lvl0`. If that doesn't work, try grouping by only one column.

Comment: i have made a sqlfiddle. please see http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ae9b7b/21/0

Comment: It seems to work with `SELECT DISTINCT lvl3,lvl2,lvl1,lvl0 FROM table GROUP BY lvl3` but it has to be _grouped by the last value containing column_, otherwise it doesn't give accurate result. Thanks  @FunkFortyNiner for valuable tip. I'll keep running it to see if any discrepancy comes up.

Comment: ok. Have you tried the (1st) answer below?

Comment: tried many variations. Giving very erratic results. Not consistent at all. In some cases values are being repeated, in others some unique rows are being left out entirely. i have tried on lines of  `GROUP BY lvl3` i.e. grouping by last populated column. May be there is a different way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

looking to your sample seems you are looking

```
SELECT DISTINCT lvl0,lvl1,lvl2,lvl3 
FROM table; 
where lvl2 is not null
```